# I want to be able to overwrite permissions of a channel when created

Tags: discord.js

So I am trying to make it so when someone opens a temp channel with my command it creates a channel and then it will change the permissions of it. Here is my current code:

````
        bot.on('message', msg =>{
          if(msg.content === (`${prefix}tempchannel`)) {
            var server = msg.guild;
            var name = msg.author.username;

            const Welcome = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Welcome, Here is your temp channel.`)
            .setDescription(`<@${msg.author.id}> Ask an admin at any time to close the temp channel. \n You cannot close one yourself due to safety reasons.`)

            server.channels.create(`${name} temp channel.`, { reason: `Temp channel for ${name}` })
            .then((channel) => channel.send(Welcome))

            msg.channel.send('Created a temp channel for you! Check your unreads.')

        }})``` Could someone help please?
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `permissionOverwrites` option like so

```js
server.channels.create(`${name} temp channel.`, {
  reason: `Temp channel for ${name}`,
  permissionOverwrites: [
     {
       id: msg.author.id,
       deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
  ],
})
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create

All the permissions: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS